# Not getting the desired output in python

Tags: python

```
def dict_invert(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''
    result = {}

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

    return result
```

In the above program, all outputs are correct

```
a
Out[82]: {2: 6, 4: 6, 6: 6, 8: 6}

dict_invert(a)
Out[83]: {6: [8, 2, 4, 6]}
```

but according to my assignment, I need `{6: [2, 4, 6, 8]}` as the output.
What should I do?

Comment: Sort it: `return {key: sorted(value) for key, value in result.items()}`

Comment: Keep working until you've solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting it after appending like so:

```
def dict_invert(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''
    result = {}

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
        result[v].sort()

    return result
```

**Update:**

The efficiency will be fine due to the fact python's algorithm [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is good for sorting already sorted data.
If you wish for even better efficiency you may use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) as so:

```
import bisect
def dict_invert(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''
    result = {}

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        bisect.insort(result.setdefault(v, []), k)

    return result
```

Due to the fact the data isn't huge and without any complicated custom equality operators (it's an int comparison) I believe you will see almost no difference.

Recreating the dict as a sorted dict though will waste both space and CPU time therefore it's less suggested.

**Update 2:**

Code with benchmarks:

```
import bisect
import timeit

d = {2: "6", 4: "6", 6: "6", 8:"6"}

def dict_invert(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''
    result = {}

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        bisect.insort(result.setdefault(v, []), k)

    return result

def dict_invert2(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''
    result = {}

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
        result[v].sort()

    return result

def dict_invert3(d):
    '''
    d: dict
    Returns an inverted dictionary according to the instructions above
    '''
    result = {}

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

    return {k: sorted(v) for k, v in result.iteritems()}

print(timeit.timeit("dict_invert(d)", setup="from __main__ import dict_invert, d"))
print(timeit.timeit("dict_invert2(d)", setup="from __main__ import dict_invert2, d"))
print(timeit.timeit("dict_invert3(d)", setup="from __main__ import dict_invert3, d"))
```

Output for python 2:

```
2.4553718788
2.59005746839
2.88147985275
```

Output for python 3 (changing `iteritems()` to `items()`):

```
2.56672796628521
2.999647860343478
3.4022091183182583
```

Comment: You don't need to sort it each time.  You can instead `return [sorted(v) for v in result]`

Comment: Sorting an almost-sorted list does not waste CPU cycles due to the algorithm python uses internally. But, if you really want, and it's a lot of data with lots of computation for equality (not the case) you may use bisect. Recreating a new list or dict in the end is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

> items()¶
>
> Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs.
>
> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary  order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and  depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

The same is valid for `iteritems`

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)